# Can I get Fb Link of a status if I have status_id from FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Using facebook FQL, I got status_id, message and time. But I also want a link to that status. This link should direct me to that status on facebook.com . Is there any easy way to do this? Thanks..

**Edit**

**Code:**

```
SELECT status_id, time, message, comment_info, like_info
FROM status WHERE uid = me() 
AND time > 1325356200 AND time < 1356978600 
ORDER BY status_id
```

Can I get url to my first status update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT status_id, time, message, comment_info, like_info
FROM status WHERE uid = me() 
AND time > 1325356200 AND time < 1356978600 
ORDER BY status_id
```

Using status_id,

you can get facebook link using, https://www.facebook.com/{{ username }}/posts/{{ status_id }}

Answer (score 1):

You can query **permalink**, for example:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20post_id%2Cmessage%2Cpermalink%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%3Dme()

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

Comment: as far as I know, stream is limited to last 50 posts or last 30 days.. what If I want permalink of my first status update?